# Curl is not printing the random number generated by rand() function

Tags: php, curl, random

I am trying to send a OTP using Ringcaptcha and using the following code.

```
$randnum = rand(100000,1000000);
$cmd = 'curl -k -X POST --data-urlencode "api_key=xxxxxxxxx" --data-urlencode "phone=+911234567890" --data-urlencode code=$randnum https://api.ringcaptcha.com/yyyyyyyyyyyy/code/sms';
exec($cmd,$result);
```

this code doesn't out put a random number everytime.

```
$echo randnum
```

outputs a different number everytime, but curl doesn't do that.

I tried all the combinations like ' , " and "code=".$randnum etc. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$echo randnum` with `echo $randnum`.

Comment: `$cmd = 'curl -k -X POST --data-urlencode "api_key=xxxxxxxxx" --data-urlencode "phone=+911234567890" --data-urlencode code='.$randnum.' https://api.ringcaptcha.com/yyyyyyyyyyyy/code/sms';`

Answer (score 0):

Could you change single quotes to double quotes, and double quotes to single quotes around curl. Like the following.

`$cmd = "curl -k -X POST --data-urlencode 'api_key=xxxxxxxx' --data-urlencode 'phone=+911234567890' --data-urlencode code=$randnum https://api.ringcaptcha.com/yyyyyyyyyyyy/code/sms";`